# Set UIView's corner radius to half of the view's width automatically

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

I have a few views whose size is not hardcoded, but determined via constraints and I need those views to be round.
Is there a way to set the cornerRadius property "dynamically", e.g. depending on the actual size of the object?
I know that if this view is inside a UIViewController, I can get the width via `roundView.frame.width` and set the layer.cornerRadius property there, but the round views aren't contained in a viewController, but managed by another simple UIView.
Thank you in advance!
Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override layoutSubviews method of View class and set the cornerRadius value there. Lets say you want cornerRadius to be half of width of the view:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
}
```

Comment: And usually a good idea to add a `super.layoutSubviews()` imo.

Comment: @TravisGriggs ah definitely, thanks for the comment. I updated the answer :))

Comment: I actually did that without thinking about it, almost like standard procedure imho :D But thanks for the hint and updated answer guys 

Answer (score 1):

Easy to achieve this with RxSwift by observing Key Path.

```
extension UIView{

    func cornerHalf(){
        clipsToBounds = true
        rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.bounds))
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Just call in `init` method, the code seems simpler by declaration , instead of being distributed two place. Especially, the logic is commonly exsited in your project.

Call like this:

```
 let update: UIButton = {
     let btn = UIButton()
     // more config
     btn.cornerHalf()
     return btn
 }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access them through your simple view that contains them. If your simple container view doesn't have those round view as instances, then you can access them by iterating through its subviews array.
 When you get a hold of the view you can access their frame.size.width and set the layer.corner radius property to that value.

Comment: The question is when will the container view know the actual size of the subview? Because in the init() method, it tells me 512px while in reality it's 60.

Comment: well I think it cannot know the actual size in the init method because its frame is set by the controller that presents it.You can set the frame in init but it can be changed by the controller. So you can try accessing it in the controller and adding the corner radius and not in the init method.